# how to adding an arr include many "src" of images into a source of image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a div that contains an image tag and I want to push an array which has many elements of src images into a source of that `<img>` I've created.
Here my code but it not working.

```js
var push = "<div class='card'><img class='front' src=''><img class = 'back' src = 'images/back.png' </div>";

var images = ["images/s1.jpg", "images/s2.jpg", "images/s3.jpg", "images/s4.jpg", "images/s5.jpg", "images/s6.jpg", "images/s7.jpg", "images/s8.jpg"]

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  $(".content").append(push);
}

var images = $('.card').children('img').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('src')
}).get()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? Also where is your HTML?

Comment: i want to push var images into a src=" " of img tag have class="front".

Comment: "i want create a that contain an" -- what?

Comment: sorry format mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var images = ["images/s1.jpg","images/s2.jpg","images/s3.jpg","images/s4.jpg","images/s5.jpg","images/s6.jpg","images/s7.jpg","images/s8.jpg"]

for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
    $('.content').append('<div class="card"><img class="front" src="'+images[i]+'"><img class="back" src="images/back.png"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assume you have div:

```
<div id='some_div' class='card'></div>
```

and then append your img-s to it:

```
var images = ["images/s1.jpg","images/s2.jpg","images/s3.jpg","images/s4.jpg","images/s5.jpg","images/s6.jpg","images/s7.jpg","images/s8.jpg"]

for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
      $('#some_div').append("<img src='"+images[i]+"' />");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML should be in your HTML. Anytime you write JavaScript with HTML markup in it, that should be a red flag.

Note: requires [`<template>` support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template).

HTML:

We have an empty `<ul>` containing a `<template>` element. We want to use a ul instead of a regular div, because lists are more semantic and accessible. For blind users especially, user agents will tell them in advance how many items are in the list, so they can skip ahead if they want.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="content">
    <template>
      <li class="card">
        <img class="front" src=""/>
        <img class="back" src="images/back.png"/>
      </li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

First we create an empty document fragment, which we will append items to. Then for each image, we clone the template’s contents and adjust the markup (specifically, setting the `src` attribute of the first image), and then append that clone to the fragment. Finally we append the fragment with all the clones in it to the container list. This technique is better than appending each of the clones to the list separately, causing a re-render each time. (Re-renders are very slow.)

```
/* $ === jQuery */

var images = ["images/s1.jpg","images/s2.jpg","images/s3.jpg","images/s4.jpg","images/s5.jpg","images/s6.jpg","images/s7.jpg","images/s8.jpg"];

var frag = new DocumentFragment();
var template = $('.content > template').get(0).content; // see <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content>

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var item = template.querySelector('.card').cloneNode(true);
  $(item).children('.front').attr('src', images[i]);
  frag.append(item);
}

// or you could use `Array#forEach`, if supported
// images.forEach(function (imgsrc) {
//   var item = template.querySelector('.card').cloneNode(true);
//   $(item).children('.front').attr('src', imgsrc);
//   frag.append(item);
// })

$('.content').append(Array.from(frag.children));
```

#semantics | #accessibility | #interoperability | #performance